# Code Simplification Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Right, an easy one for most.
So with in a health App i have several text field for calculating a users BMI. I have the following code actions ALL EACH linked to a button to calculate the BMI. The idea being that if all the height fields and weight fields are empty then the app disables the button. the fields are linked to cmDisable and feetDisable etc... Can anyone think of a MUCH simpler way of doing this?
Many Thanks

```
- (IBAction)cmDisable:(id)sender {
    if (((UITextField*)sender).text.length > 0) {
        [_calculateButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        [_calculateButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}

- (IBAction)feetDisable:(id)sender {
    if (((UITextField*)sender).text.length > 0) {
        [_calculateButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        [_calculateButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
- (IBAction)inchesDisable:(id)sender {
    if (((UITextField*)sender).text.length > 0) {
        [_calculateButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        [_calculateButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
- (IBAction)kgDisable:(id)sender {
    if (((UITextField*)sender).text.length > 0) {
        [_calculateButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        [_calculateButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
- (IBAction)stoneDisable:(id)sender {
    if (((UITextField*)sender).text.length > 0) {
        [_calculateButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        [_calculateButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
- (IBAction)poundsDisable:(id)sender {
    if (((UITextField*)sender).text.length > 0) {
        [_calculateButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        [_calculateButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code works, consider asking it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Just link them all to the same action? The inner code is identical.

Comment: How do I link them all into the same action if their all from different text fields?

Comment: make another just like the rest, call it generically "pressedDisable:", then in IB, visit each text field, and control-drag from each to your view controller (under where the scenes are listed).  A menu will popup with all of those actions.  Select the generic one.  Once it's working, you can delete these others.

Comment: KVO is what you really want. Observe the values of the model. If any value does not meet the threshold, then set the corresponding button disabled.

Comment: Are you using CoreData to manage the values represented in the text fields? If so there is a very easy solution.

Comment: This might be a bit over the top, but every iOS developer should now this technique: http://chris.eidhof.nl/posts/intentions.html though I don't like replacing massive view controller with massiver storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I am understanding correctly, you want to disable a button when all fields are empty.

What you could do is add all the buttons to a collection from Interface Builder. So you would have

```
    IBOutletCollection(UITextField) NSArray *fields;   //Linked to all fields
```

Then you would connect all fields to the "Editing Ended" action for UITextFields. The method would like the following:

```
- (IBAction) fieldsValueChanged:(id) sender {
    BOOL shouldDisable = NO;

    for(UITextField *next in fields) {
        if(next.text.length > 0) {
            shouldDisable = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    [_calculateButton setEnabled:shouldDisable];
}
```